# How to concat tensors of unequal sizes in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `[64, 270]` (64 batches * 270 items) and want to add the same 200 additional items to each batch (a tensor of shape `[200]`). The result should be that each of the 64 batches contains their original 270 items plus the 200 new items that are the same for each batch.

basically `concat([64, 270], [200])` --> `[64, 470]`

How can I do that? I tried using `tf.concat`, `tf.stack`, increasing the rank of the second tensor using `tf.expand_dims` but nothing works. It always either complains about the unequal rank or unequal zeroth (batch) dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
tf.concat([x,tf.tile(y[None,...],[tf.shape(x)[0],1])], axis=1)
```

Code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,270])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (200))

z = tf.concat([x,tf.tile(y[None,...],[tf.shape(x)[0],1])], axis=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(z, {x:np.random.normal(size=(64,270)), y:np.random.normal(size=(200))}).shape)
# (64, 470)
```